# How to catch antiforgery exception and redirect to error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm migrating to .Net Core and I can't figure out how to handle anti-forgery token exceptions. This is what I want to recreate in .Net Core (Global.asax.cs, Application_Error() method):

```
RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");

Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

if (exception != null)
{
    if (exception is HttpAntiForgeryException)
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "XSRF");
    }
    else if (exception is HttpException httpException)
    {

        int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        switch (httpCode)
        {
            // Redirect based on httpCode
        }
        Response.StatusCode = httpCode;
    }
    else
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Oops");
    }

}
// Pass exception details to the target error View.
routeData.Values.Add("error", exception);
```

I started by adding the following to Startup.cs:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

That catches things like null pointer exceptions, but not 404 errors or anti-forgery token exceptions. So I added this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 400)
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/Error/HttpError400"; // <-- this code is reached but no redirect
        await next();
    }
    else if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/Error/HttpError404";
        await next();
    }
});
```

Now, when I request a non-existing page, I'm redirected to /Error/HttpError404, but when I submit my login form with a corrupted anti-forgery cookie, I still only see an empty screen and a 400 error in the Network tab of the browser. I added a breakpoint at the marked location to confirm that the code is reached. It is, but the result is the same: empty body, 400 result code.

Why does the redirect not work? How should I handle this?

Update: Here's the whole Configure() method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "fr" };
    var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

    app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 400)
        {
            context.Request.Path = "/Error/HttpError400";
            await next();
        }
        else if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            context.Request.Path = "/Error/HttpError404";
            await next();
        }
    });
    app.UseHsts();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseSession();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.Use(next => context =>
    {
        string path = context.Request.Path.Value;

        if (
            string.Equals(path, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            string.Equals(path, "/index.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // The request token can be sent as a JavaScript-readable cookie, 
            // and Angular uses it by default.
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
        }

        return next(context);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `Configure` method code of your Startup class?

Comment: @FeiHan Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute`?

Add it to your `Configure` method like this:

```cs
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
```

Add an `ErrorController`, then in your controller:

```
[Route("Error/{statusCode}")]
public IActionResult ErrorHandler(int statusCode)
{
    switch (statusCode)
    {
        case 404:
            break;
        case 500:
            break;
        case 400:
            //Redirect
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return View("Error");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for anti-forgery token exceptions. It doesn't reach the controller code.

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni I just tested it and it catches the `400` but not the actual exception so you can redirect on antiforgery exception based on the fact that it produces a `400` but you can't aquire the actual exception. But from your question, you want to redirect on a `400` which this example above does.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `IAlwaysRunResultFilter` and evaluate the content result.  Antiforgery Token exceptions return a specific `IActionResult` - `IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult`.

This was raised as an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3616) and a useful code example can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/ddbe0fef2617f94a42312f002860f8f45145f11d/test/WebSites/BasicWebSite/Filters/RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter.cs).

Comment: I don't manage this code anymore, but thanks for the suggestion. I hope it helps someone else.